# Cycles is not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hardware

I switch to Cycles rendering engine in Blender but it doesn't switch rather Blender crashes. Previously it didn't happen but now after installing an NVIDIA 710 GT 2GB graphics card it keeps happening. The graphics card is totally fine though. Other games and software runs well but not Blender anymore. I need some help and fast.

hey i tried reinstalling the driver but it's still crashing.Can you show me how to uninstall / install the driver.

Comment: You may need to uninstall/install the NVIDIA driver to get things work. Have you done that?

Comment: I tried but nothing happened. PLz show me a correct way. I need it fast.